# IOS Provisioning Profiles appstore not AdHoc

Tags: telerik, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've made a certificate and an app store distribution provisioning profile but when i try to sign my code in the Telerik AppManager, it says the app is signed with an AdHoc provisioning profile.

Am I missing something?

I triple checked that I clicked on appstore not AdHoc so I'm sure this should work or have I missed something?

Comment: You are following these procedures: http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/publishing-your-app/distribute-production/publish-ios ?

Comment: no because its for the telerik appstore and its not a cordova app

Comment: Telerik has their own app store? For iOS apps?  I believe that would run afoul of Apple's provisioning / code signing rules.

Comment: Yeah, it does. Telerik AppManager like I stated in my question

Comment: That's an app distribution platform, and it is used to distribute apps signed with either AdHoc or In House profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish iOS app built with an App Store distribution profile anywhere by the Apple App Store.  For distribution through other platforms, you will need to sign with either an AdHoc profile or an In House App Distribution profile. In House App Distribution profile requires you have an Enterprise account.

Telerik won't use the App Store distribution profile because it won't be able to use the signed binary if it did.